# What a shame they couldn’t/can't come

Tags: tense, subjunctives, could-modal

> What a shame they couldn’t come.

> What a shame they can’t come.

Is there any difference between them?

The only difference is couldn't(past) vs. can't(present).

In other words, 'couldn't' means past here?

Comment: Why do you think "couldn't" means something other than the past of "can't" here?

Answer (score 2):

> In other words, 'couldn't' means past here?

Yes

What a shame they couldn’t come. = What a shame [that at the time I asked them] they **were** unable to come.

or (said after the event has happened) = What a shame they **were** unable to come [to the event that has now ended/took place in the past].

What a shame they can’t come. = What a shame that [currently] they **are** unable to come.